# How to add last edited stamp to JComments?

Tags: extensions

Was wondering if anyone knew how i might add a last edited stamp when someone edits their post in JComments. I've added an extra column to the end of the jcomments' table called **editdate**.

Mostly not sure how to incorporate the query that will register the editdate.

The references to the edit button on the toolbar are as follows. The first in **components/com_jcomments/tpl/default/tpl_comment.php** inside the function to display the toolbar buttons:

```
if ($this->getVar('button-edit') == 1) {
                $text = JText::_('BUTTON_EDIT');
?>
    <a class="toolbar-button-edit" href="#" onclick="jcomments.editComment(<?php echo $comment->id; ?>); return false;" title="<?php echo $text; ?>"></a>
<?php
            }
```

The second in **components/com_jcomments/js/jcomments-v2.3.js** that i'm assuming points to the next location.

```
editComment: function(i){this.busyComment(i);var a=arguments;if(this.form==null){a=new Array(i,1);}return this.ajax('JCommentsEditComment', a);},
```

And the third the editcomment function in **components/com_jcomments/jcomments.ajax.php**. The save function is under it, not sure which actually saves the edit.

```
public static function editComment($id, $loadForm = 0)
    {
        if (JCommentsSecurity::badRequest() == 1) {
            JCommentsSecurity::notAuth();
        }

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $response = JCommentsFactory::getAjaxResponse();
        $comment = JTable::getInstance('Comment', 'JCommentsTable');

        if ($comment->load((int) $id)) {
            $acl = JCommentsFactory::getACL();

            if ($acl->isLocked($comment)) {
                $response->addAlert(JText::_('ERROR_BEING_EDITTED'));
            } else if ($acl->canEdit($comment)) {
                    $comment->checkout($user->id);

                    $name = ($comment->userid) ? '' : JCommentsText::jsEscape($comment->name);
                    $email = ($comment->userid) ? '' : JCommentsText::jsEscape($comment->email);
                    $homepage = JCommentsText::jsEscape($comment->homepage);
                    $text = JCommentsText::jsEscape(JCommentsText::br2nl($comment->comment));
                    $title = JCommentsText::jsEscape(str_replace("\n", '', JCommentsText::br2nl($comment->title)));

                    if (intval($loadForm) == 1) {
                        $form = JComments::getCommentsForm($comment->object_id, $comment->object_group, true);
                        $response->addAssign('comments-form-link', 'innerHTML', $form);
                    }
                    $response->addScript("jcomments.showEdit(" . $comment->id . ", '$name', '$email', '$homepage', '$title', '$text');");
                } else {
                    $response->addAlert(JText::_('ERROR_CANT_EDIT'));
                }
        }
        return $response;
    }

public static function saveComment($values = array())
    {
        if (JCommentsSecurity::badRequest() == 1) {
            JCommentsSecurity::notAuth();
        }

        $config = JCommentsFactory::getConfig();

        $response = JCommentsFactory::getAjaxResponse();
        $values = self::prepareValues($_POST);
        $comment = JTable::getInstance('Comment', 'JCommentsTable');
        $id = (int) $values['id'];

        if ($comment->load($id)) {
            $acl = JCommentsFactory::getACL();

            if ($acl->canEdit($comment)) {
                if ($values['comment'] == '') {
                    self::showErrorMessage(JText::_('ERROR_EMPTY_COMMENT'), 'comment');
                } else if (($config->getInt('comment_maxlength') != 0)
                    && ($acl->check('enable_comment_length_check') == 1)
                    && (JCommentsText::strlen($values['comment']) > $config->getInt('comment_maxlength'))) {
                    self::showErrorMessage(JText::_('ERROR_YOUR_COMMENT_IS_TOO_LONG'), 'comment');
                } else if (($config->getInt('comment_minlength') != 0)
                    && ($acl->check('enable_comment_length_check') == 1)
                    && (JCommentsText::strlen($values['comment']) < $config->getInt('comment_minlength'))) {
                    self::showErrorMessage(JText::_('ERROR_YOUR_COMMENT_IS_TOO_SHORT'), 'comment');
                } else {
                    $bbcode = JCommentsFactory::getBBCode();

                    $comment->comment = $values['comment'];
                    $comment->comment = $bbcode->filter($comment->comment);
                    $comment->published = $acl->check('autopublish');


                    if (($config->getInt('comment_title') != 0) && isset($values['title'])) {
                        $comment->title = stripslashes((string)$values['title']);
                    }

                    if (($config->getInt('author_homepage') == 1) && isset($values['homepage'])) {
                        $comment->homepage = JCommentsText::url($values['homepage']);
                    } else {
                        $comment->homepage = '';
                    }

                    $result = JCommentsEventHelper::trigger('onJCommentsCommentBeforeChange', array(&$comment));

                    if (in_array(false, $result, true)) {
                        return $response;
                    }

                    $comment->store();
                    $comment->checkin();

                    JCommentsEventHelper::trigger('onJCommentsCommentAfterChange', array(&$comment));

                    if ($config->getInt('enable_notification') == 1) {
                        if ($config->check('notification_type', 1) == true) {
                            JComments::sendNotification($comment, false);
                        }
                    }
                    $html = JCommentsText::jsEscape(JComments::getCommentItem($comment));
                    $response->addScript("jcomments.updateComment(" . $comment->id . ", '$html');");
                }
            } else {
                $response->addAlert(JText::_('ERROR_CANT_EDIT'));
            }
        }
        return $response;
```

Basically just wanting it to add a current date to the editdate column on send. There may be other references to it, but i haven't found any. This is where the trail led, and i'm assuming a query needs inserted, just not sure where or how to insert the data into the database. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a short answer of mine would be, if you created an extra column in the jcomments table, that column (if MySQL) should be a timestamp type column in the table. It would just automatically update the date-time at every change/edit/insert of the rows, thus you do not have to edit the php files for this purpose. You should just set the column that way.

So it should be:

```
editdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I am not the best mysql guru here but with something like this query line you can change the field type of the table column in your database.

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`jcomments` MODIFY COLUMN `editdate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If there is any mistake in the above query, someone (like '@mickmackusa' - who is really a db query guru here) probably will be so kind to fix it a bit.

**reference:** http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx

Comment: If that's the case, then i'm just not sure where to put that. The column exists in this test data [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4pqz9MFGGaQ1ucB3nmw1De/0] Structure for editdate column is **COLUMN: editdate TYPE: datetime DEFAULT: As defined: 0000-00-00 00:00:00** All other fields are blank or unchecked.

Comment: Ok, you were right. The setting i was missing in the column was **ATTRIBUTES: on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** Added the time stamp in the column. Now can just use query to display. Thanks.